# Modified Bncert command has taken site offline

Tags: wordpress, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have made a silly mistake;
So I have a LightSail instance to run my Wordpress Bitnami website. I had recently got the domain working but decided that I wanted to generate an SLL certificate so decided to run the bncert-tool function in the console.

I kept getting an error message saying that the 'example.com' and 'www.examples.com' DNS public IP addresses were different. After not being able to fix this issue I ran (rather stupidly) the following command to skip the DNS record check:

> sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool --perform_public_ip_validation 0 --perform_dns_validation 0

I now have two issues:

1. The website is now unreachable via a browser (was previously working right before this).
2. When I try to run the simple sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool command I get the following output from the Bitnami console:

> Bitnami installation directoryPlease type a directory that contains a
> Bitnami installation. The default installation directory for Linux
> installers is a directory inside /opt. Bitnami installation directory
> [/opt/bitnami]:

Note: this is following an instance reboot so would expect it to come up with the usual default directory. As it has in the past.

If there anyway I can fix this? :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitnami engineer here,

The Bitnami HTTPS configuration tool modifies the Apache's main configuration file to configure the SSL certificates and the redirections you selected. You can simply recover those files with the backup files the tool generates before making any change. You will find those backup files inside the `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf` and `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami` directories. After replacing the files, please restart the server

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

Note: You can also modify your DNS settings to properly configure the www and non-www domains to point to your instance so you won't need to modify the Apache conf

Comment: Right I see. Well I am using Cloudflare as the DNS so the more I learn makes me think that I should have left it as it was! (learning curve...). 

Looking at both those directories, there are quite a lot of files. 

I presume I need to only copy the httpd.conf.back.202101220056 file from /conf and the bitnami-apps-prefix.conf.back.202101220056 and bitnami.conf.back.202101220056 from those directories to a different one?

Alternatively, as I now realise I don't need the SLL via Apache, maybe I can just wipe the existing one??

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I understand situation a bit better now but a new question has emerged.
I have posted this for anyone that's interested:
[How to restore Apache configuration file in Bitnami](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65860077/how-to-restore-apache-configuration-file-in-bitnami)