# How to restore Apache configuration file in Bitnami

Tags: wordpress, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

When running the bncert-tool on my LightSail server, I have accidentally modified some of Apache's configuration files which I now need to revert from the backup directories.
See previous question and answer here for more info: [Modified Bncert command has taken site offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65842018/modified-bncert-command-has-taken-site-offline)

I have looked in both the `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf` and `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami` directories and can see a series of files including **httpd.conf.back.202101220056** (/conf) and **bitnami.conf.back.202101220056** (/bitnami).

My question is which backup files do I need need to copy to which location?
I assume it is performed via a 'mv' command.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a bitnami stack the main Apache server configuration file is (httpd.conf)

When you are configuring server for SSL this is usually done in the file (bitnami.conf)

I would start by replacing the current bitnami.conf with the original bitnami.conf. Then restart your server so that the changes that effect. bitnami.conf is located in the directory apache2/conf/bitnami

If that does not fix it then replace the current httpd.conf with the original httpd.conf. Then restart your server so that the changes that effect. httpd.conf is located in the directory apache2/conf .

Note you will find it a lot easier to modify server files if you connect to your server with FileZilla. You can delete and drag and drop to copy files with FileZilla.

Comment: Thanks a million. Got filezilla working and fixed the issue. The file bitnami.conf wasn't actually present to renamed and copied over the backup and its all working now. Many thanks :-)

Comment: glad you got it fixed

Comment: Thanks MikeMoy for helping this Bitnami user. As you said, the user needed to recover both files and restart the Apache server to move back to the previous state. The Bitnami HTTPS configuration tool backs the files up before making any change.